# How do you sort all selectboxes on a page alphabetically that has optgroup's without moving the options out of their respective groups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu

I need help with a dilemma. I have no idea how to solve this problem. I need to sort all select boxes on a webpage alphabetically (a, b, c, d,...) by option groups (`<optgroup>`), then sort the options in each option group alphabetically, without taking them out of their respective group.

I need this to happen by calling the selectbox's ID, after it is loaded. Preferably, in pure JavaScript, but if that's not possible, JQuery can be used instead.

Can you handle this? If so, please help steer me in the right direction.

Thanks in Advance!

-James A.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way with javascript to turn a json object into a sorted html select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431819/best-way-with-javascript-to-turn-a-json-object-into-a-sorted-html-select)

Comment: @Dave That's a solution for JSON. I need a solution by calling the html selectbox by id and manipulating its contents, in either pure js, or jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept is the same as what I referenced in my comment above. See the `function orderOptgroups` below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    orderOptgroups();
});

function orderOptgroups() {
    $("select").each(function() {
        var $select = $(this);
        var $groups = $select.find("optgroup");
        $groups.remove();
        $groups = $groups.sort(function(g1, g2) {
            return g1.label.localeCompare(g2.label);      
        });      
        $select.append($groups);
        $groups.each(function() {
            var $group = $(this);
            var options = $group.find("option");
            options.remove();
            options = options.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.innerHTML.localeCompare(b.innerHTML);
            });
            $group.append(options);
        });
    });
}
```

```css
select {
    width:100px;
    height:250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
        <option value="value11">Label C</option>
        <option value="value21">Label A</option>
        <option value="value31">Label B</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 3">
        <option value="value12">Label F</option>
        <option value="value22">Label D</option>
        <option value="value32">Label E</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
        <option value="value13">Label X</option>
        <option value="value23">Label Y</option>
        <option value="value33">Label Z</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<select multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Group C">
        <option value="value11">Label 9</option>
        <option value="value21">Label 8</option>
        <option value="value31">Label 7</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group B">
        <option value="value12">Label 5</option>
        <option value="value22">Label 6</option>
        <option value="value32">Label 4</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group A">
        <option value="value13">Label 3</option>
        <option value="value23">Label 1</option>
        <option value="value33">Label 2</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank You but this does does not also sort the optgroups in alphebetical order. Very good attempt though.

Comment: The sort concept is the same at the `optgroup` level. Updated answer

Comment: That try was even better! However, if you have multiple selectboxes on a page with different values and different option groups they all get mixed in together. I highly appreciate it, and value your time, but it still doesn't work. I was hoping this question could help both me and other programmers here on SO, but since you've worked so hard on a solution, and it still doesn't work, you can give up if you wish. =-(

Comment: You didn't mention that you needed this to work for multiple selects on the same page. Updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: You're a RockStar! This will help a lot of people!